# Which version of browser's , angular Js fully support ?? firefox, Chrome , Safari , IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

We have build a app in angularJs v1.2.9 .

So i want to know how many browser supported by angularJs & how many not ???? So we can take final decision of launching .

Thanks-
Nishchit

Comment: Shouldn't you do that before you start on a project? http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

Comment: @putvande When we start project it was angular1.1.5 & now it is 1.2.9, And also in angular blog IE detail is given , I am looking for firefox and safari mostly

Comment: That is because the other browsers update themselves.